# Why does my Layout appear blank after moving components from the palette, Android Studio 3.1.3?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android development and am trying to create a simple menu in my main_activity.xml file.  When I click on the file and the layout appears, the components I drag to the "device" does not appear. You can see in the picture there should be the default "Hello World" text, and a button.

[image]

Comment: You can see the message you got.
Firstly move your object to the `root`layout,
Select the object in Component Tree at the left pane. This will show the attributes of the your object.
You can then constrain and give it properties like size, text, and so on...

Comment: I'm still a bit confused on this.  What is the root layout and how can I move the objects there?  I looked over the buttons properties and don't know how/where to constrain them from there.  Remember this is my first experience with Android Studio, use small words.

Comment: I urge you to kindly goto official documentation to start your career in programming. This will be lengthy as you are just starting